# What is the difference of objects and filter in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, orm, mongoengine

In `mongoengine` there are two ways of querying objects(documents) in a collection:

```
Test.object(category="blabla")
```

And

```
Test.object.filter(category="blabla")
```

And they return same result. But the question is what is the difference? Performance? or they are just alias of each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference, [one is an alias of the other](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset/base.py#L214-L217):

```
def filter(self, *q_objs, **query):
    """An alias of :meth:`~mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.__call__`
    """
    return self.__call__(*q_objs, **query)
```